# apache2 simple mod_rewrite redirect not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a simple apache2 mod_rewrite rule working, but I have had no signs of success.  I have placed the following lines or slight derivations of them in my apache2.conf, under my virtualhost in sites-available,and under the directories / and /var/www in sites-available.  Each time I restarted apache to see if any changes took effect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/banana$  http://localhost/index.html [L,R,QSA]
```

Above I am trying to redirect "/banana" to "/index.html".  It does not work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `/` in front of banana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment. Remove the slash in front of banana. It will add the slash automatically so you don't need to put it or it will never match. And you really don't need the QSA flag in this instance. Try this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^banana$  http://localhost/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works!  I placed these lines in the directory entry corresponding to my root dir (/var/www) and it worked.  Thanks for your answer.